# Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Hii , I am new to JQuery, please help me how to highlight specific characters  with jQuery autocomplete  plug-in .,

my question is when i entered a xyz in a text box ,then with auto-complete we can get the letters starts with xyz with highlighting but in case the requested letters are there in middle of a big label then how to highlight those letters

Selected word : xyz

my desired  list should display :1)abc **xyz** 
                                 2)bcs **xyz**

please help me

Comment: autocomplete will match the words that contain the typed word anywhere in the source strings; unless you are using a custom source (JSON or callback).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see in this example it's highlighted by default..

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Maybe your stylesheet doesn't hightlight  tags (not default in all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use replace function, with normal string replace or with regular expression for more complicated replaces.

```
var searchQuery = 'xyz'
var searchResult1 = 'abc xyz'
var searchResult2 = 'bcs xyz'

//display abc <b>xyz</b>
var displayResult1 = searchResult1.replace(searchQuery,'<b>'+searchQuery+'</b>');

//display bcs <b>xyz</b>
var displayResult2 = searchResult2.replace(searchQuery,'<b>'+searchQuery+'</b>');
```